# APPHOST9601 : An app can’t load remote web content in the local context. Windows phone 8.1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I have a cordova project with ionic. I am trying to build windows phone 8.1 build in Visual studio 2015 but I get above error.

Things already tried :

1) installed whitelist plugin at my project folder.

2) Added whitlist URLs in config.xml

3) Added ApplicationContentUriRules in appxmanifest file.

4) Added meta tag in index.html for "Content-Security-Policy" as per cordova documents.

Nothing works.

Are there any workaround ? Any solution ?

I am trying to load scripts of from JQuery and google cdn, also I have google map feature in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to load scripts of from JQuery and google cdn, also I have google map feature in my app.

Remote scripts can't be loaded in the local context in UWP. If you want it to work, you need to put it inside a web context, which is a [x-ms-webview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I have moved to web contex now.